Exclude variable-length suffix from python list/array which could be zero
I often have occasion to remove the last n elements from a Python list, where n is set by some other part of the program and can sometimes equal zero. If I just do
shortened_list = full_list[:-n]

then this works when n>0 but returns the empty list if n==0, whereas I would like it to then return the full list. I end up having to write
shortened_list = full_list if n==0 else full_list[:-n]

Is there a more compact way? It's a relatively small increase in code length, but it does arise quite a lot and often what happens is that I code it the wrong way as line one above, then only after some debugging do I trace it back to this mistake and correct it to line two above.
The same thing can happen in numpy, pytorch, pandas etc, where the indexing can be over any dimension, e.g.,
shortened_array = full_array[:,:,:-n]

works for n>0 but gives an empty array for n==0.

How about full_list[:len(full_list) - n]?

Extract a helper function? Looks like a canonical reason to do so: a small pure function, trivial to implement and unittest.

@MechanicPig yeah that is probably better than the 'if-else' line anyway

@STerliakov as I understand, I'd then have to rewrite this function for each new python project

As far as I know, there is no built-in way of doing this but you could write a function:
def get_last_n(full_list, n):
    return full_list if n==0 else full_list[:-n]

and then use it in your code like this:
shortened_list = get_last_n(full_list, n)

This isn't that much shorter but at least it lowers the chance of a typo.

Thanks. The problem, also re STerialkov's comment, is having to share this function across all my Python projects. Another thing is that this indexing issue arises not only in native lists but also in things like numpy arrays and the structures built on top of them, like in pytorch and pandas. I guess I should add this part to my question.
